# Coded UI test does not run under Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have got some Coded UI tests using MSTest. They used to work OK on VS 2010. Now I have migrated to VS2012, they build fine, and I can run tehm form the command line, but I cannot run them in the IDE, because it fails to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework.dll. I tried adding that to the GAC using gacutil, which moved the probelm on. After several iterations of that I am stuck at not resolving Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.XmlSerializers.

I'm sure this should Just Work, did I forget to install something? Does something need re-installing? Otherwise, where can I find that missing assembly, which does not appear to be installed in my machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Check that you are using **VS Premium** or **VS Ultimate**. Other forums recommend reinstalling or repairing VS2012.

Comment: Tried that, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Was reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) earlier today when researching a related item & saw this mentioned:

> VSTest.Console.exe is optimized for performance and is used in place of MSTest.exe in Visual Studio 2012.

Try switching from MSTest to VSTest.Console and see if that solves your problem.